# How to call powershell commands in a row from python

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I am trying to run this ps command within a python script :

> subprocess.call('powershell.exe $username = "admin@example.com";$password = Get-Content "C:/Scripts/user.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString;$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ` -argumentlist $username, $password;Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred;Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@example, shell=TRUE)

So basically as you can understand I call this command within the script and autologin in azure and get the user. My problem is that I am getting this error :

> 'ConvertTo-SecureString' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Any ideas? Thank you so much in advance everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this as it was a normal CMD line. Use CMD's escape symbol `^` before special chars.
**Example:**

```
powershell.exe -Command Get-ChildItem ^| ConvertTo-Json
```

In *difficult cases* it's easier to use `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand ENCCMD` where [`ENCCMD` is Base64-encoded text.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand)

---

Avoid using MSOL Powershell CmdLets, use [Microsoft Graph Api /users](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/users) natively in python.